# If the moon's orbit decays- how would it effect the moon's phases?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, moons, orbital-decay

If a planet passed near the moon and caused its orbit to decay down to earth- how long could it take and how would that effect the visible phases of the moon on earth?

Comment: I think this question should be in the Astronomy SE